# What queryset should I do to select all One-to-one relations that are broken?

Tags: django

I have this 2 models :

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ... some other fields ...

class AssetConstructorData(models.Model):
    asset = models.OneToOneField(
        Asset,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
        related_name='constructor_data',
    )
    ... some other fields ...
```

For some historical reason, I have some One-to-one which are broken : some AssetConstructorData object has not their corresponding Asset object.
I would like to delete all AssetConstructorData objects that are broken.

Actually I have done :

```
for cd in AssetConstructorData.objects.all():
    try:
        cd.asset
    except Asset.DoesNotExist:
        cd.delete()
```

Which is definitively not optimized : Is that possible to make a queryset that selects all broken relations ?

I tried with `.filter(asset=None)` and `.filter(asset__isnull=True)` but it does not work.

Comment: Your model definition prohibits `asset` from being null, and `on_delete` is set to cascade - so how would that situation ever arise?

Comment: If this is a one-time problem, just make it in an inefficient way and wait. Otherwise fix the bug that causes this regularly. And if you have millions of records, make an SQL query directly in your DBMS.

Comment: @solarissmoke : on a previous version, `on_delete` was not set to cascade and some delete occured meanwhile...

Comment: @Timur :  of course it is a one time problem, but I wondered if it was possible by using Django ORM...

Comment: Sneak up on it? No idea if this will work, but `.filter(asset__created__isnull=True)` maybe?  Or `=None`? What value *does* following the broken chain return?

Comment: I already tried that (`count()` gives 0). I tried also the opposite with `.exclude(asset__created__isnull=False)`  : it does not work too.